# Tkinter itemcget not working as intended. Can't print when saved in a variable

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

```
def choose_word():
    card_num = random.randint(0, len(french_vocab_list))
    canvas.itemconfig(french_word, text=french_vocab_list[card_num])
    test = canvas.itemcget(card_front, 'state')
    print(test, type(test))
    window.after(3000, flip_card)

def flip_card():
    check_state = canvas.itemcget(card_front, 'state')
    print(check_state)
    if check_state == "normal":
        print("If condition fulfilled")
        canvas.itemconfig(card_front, state="hidden")
        canvas.itemconfig(card_back, state="normal")
```

The only thing that gets printed is <class: str>

why does the check_state not get evaluated? Why doesn't it print the string that it saves into "test"?

First ever post so if I did something wrong when posting please be patient.

I've put print statements in the code to try to see what is getting assigned when doing this, but I'm not sure what is going wrong. I think there is a better way to use the conditional statement, but I am still either not finding it or not understanding the documentation well enough.

Comment: The default value of the `state` option appears to be an empty string, rather than `'normal'` - that seems wrong, but it is what it is.  Perhaps change your `check_state == "normal"` test to `check_state != "hidden"`...

Comment: You solved my problem that I have been struggling on for over an hour. According to this documentation 
https://tkinter-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/widgets/canvas.html
the default state is normal, but as you say, that is not true. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please try, when asking a question, to create a minimally reproducible example of the problem https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, so that they can respond to it faster and give more detailed answers.